# Remove part of the content of a file from the last commit and apply it to the working tree

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

So, I've accidentally made the commit in which a few of the changes (all of them are in the same file) had to be made in the next commit. I want to delete parts of the changes made in the last commit from it and apply them to the working tree (so I can use them for a new commit). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git reset -p @^
git commit --amend
git commit -a
```

That's "choose changes made by the last commit to un-stage, replace the last commit with a new one (with the staged content that has those changes removed), then make a new commit from the current content in the work tree."

Comment: Ah, that minimality obsession :-)